# PHP как распаковать zip с подкаталогами?

Tags: php, zip

Нужен код, который распаковывает zip архив со всеми подпапками полностью сохраняя структуру.

Пробовал вот так, но такой код не распаковывает файлы, находящиеся в подпапках:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($filename);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($structure);
  $zip->close();

}
```

Comment: Неужели поиск в интернете информации про работу с zip-архивами не помог?

Comment: К примеру вот этот код, который часто приводится в интернете распаковывает только файлы первого уровня, подпапки же не распаковывает:$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($filename);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($structure);
  $zip->close();

}

Comment: Проверил этот код у себя — неправда, он распаковывает архив целиком со всеми подпапками.

Comment: Странно, может у меня архивы кривые...у меня почему то подпапки он упорно не видит

Comment: Понял в чем причина, у меня файлы в подпапках на Кириллице написаны, если переименовать на латиницу - то все работает отлично!

Answer (score 1):

Понял в чем причина, код работает как надо только если файлы в подпапках архива написаны Латиницей, у меня же они были написаны Кириллицей.