# PHP $zip->extractTo распаковать файлы и подпапки с именами на Кириллице

Tags: php, zip

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть код, который распаковывает zip архив:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($filename);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($structure);
  $zip->close();
  }
```

Если в архиве все имена файлов и подкаталогов написаны Латиницей, то проблем нет, распаковка происходит со всеми подпапками.
Если же имена файлов и подпапок на Кириллице то эти файлы он либо не распаковывает либо делает крякозябры.
Как можно доработать данный код?

Хотелось бы именно доработать данный код, а не переименовывать каждый файл в архиве с Кириллицы на Латиницу.

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PHP как распаковать zip с подкаталогами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269864/php-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-zip-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Не, там вопрос решается переименованием файлов в архиве на Латиницу, мне же нужно решить вопрос именно с файлами на Кириллице.

Comment: вопрос один и тот же, только потом ты его дополнил.